# MethodNotAllowedException in Laravel 4

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am getting this error `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException` after submitting the form, I dont know why but I have tried everything but no success.

Below is my code snippet,

**Views**

**myView.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'postDetails/updatePost','files'=>true),'POST') }}

<ul>
<li>
    {{ Form::select('postType',array(''=>'Type','Items'=>'Items','Services'=>'Services','Skills'=>'Skills'),Input::old(postType),array('id'=>'postType')) }}
</li>
<li>
    {{ Form::select('postCategory',array(''=>'Category'),Input::old('postCategory'),array('id'=>'postCategory')) }}
</li>
<li>
    {{ Form::text('postPrice',Input::old(postPrice) }}
</li>
</ul>
<p>
   {{ Form::textarea('postDescription',$post->postDescription) }}
</p>
<p>
   {{ Form::submit('Update') }}
</p>

{{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('postDetails/updatePost', array('as'=>'updatePost','uses'=>'UserController@post_update_post_details'));
```

**Controller**

**UserController.php**

```
public function post_update_post_details()
{
    return View::make('demo')->with('msg','Successfully Updated');      
}
```

Below is **screenshot** of the error,

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First of all try it View**::**Make:

```
public function post_update_post_details()
{
    return View::Make('demo')->with('msg','Successfully Updated');       
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry that was typo.I have mentioned correctly `View::Make` in my controller.php already. And I am sure this not a problem. Anyways edited my question. Thanks!